# need help in sap.m.Tree binding in SAP Ui5

Tags: tree, sapui5

I have a requirement to use a [Tree control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.Tree) in my Ui5 application. I'm using json model binding here. I do have an array with unique roleids and odata results using which I need to build a tree structure, set it to my JSON model and bind it to UI control.

first array as given below:

[0 : "attribute"
1 : "role"
2 : "roleCollection"]
length: 3
[[Prototype]: Array(0)

Odata.results as shown below:

0> roleid : "attribute" value: "Test attribute" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

1> roleid : "attribute" value: "Test attribute2" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

2> roleid: "role" value: "Test role" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

3> roleid: "role" value: "Test role" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

4> roleid: "RoleCollection" value: "Test RC1" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

5> roleid: "roleCollection" value: "Test RC2" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

6> roleid: "roleCollection" value: "Test RC3" modifiedBy: "anonymous" projectid: "Test789"

using these I have to build Tree structure roleid as my parent and values are child elements, bind it to Tree control:

```
<Tree id="Tree" items="{path: 'rModel>/'}" toggleOpenState="onPressTree">
    <StandardTreeItem id="_IDTreeItem1" title="{rModel>roleid}"   detailPress=""/>  
</Tree>
```

How can I build a tree structure?

I tried the below code, however it's not showing up data on screen:

const aUnique = [...new Set(oData.results.map(item => item.roleid))];

```
                console.log("array Unique"+ aUnique);

                var b = oData.results, 
        
                    mainArry = [],
                    obj = {};
                 for ( var i = 0; i < aUnique.length; i++ ) {
                    mainArry.push(aUnique[i]);
                    var temparry = [];
                    for ( var e = 0; e < b.length; e++ ) {                                             
                       if (aUnique [i] === b[e].roleid ){
                            temparry.push(b[e].value);                           
                        }                           
                    }
                    mainArry.push(temparry);
                    temparry ="";
                    obj.roleid = mainArry; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved.I got this fixed as this below:

```js
var dataSet = oData.results;

const mainNode = [];

const aUnique = [...new Set(oData.results.map(item =>
    item.roleid))];

aUnique.forEach(e => {
    var nodeObj = {};
    nodeObj.text = e;
    nodeObj.node = dataSet.filter(d => { return d.roleid == e; });
    nodeObj.node.forEach(n => {
        n.text = n.value;
    });
    mainNode.push(nodeObj);
});
console.log(mainNode);
that.rdModel.setData(mainNode); //rmodel is a json model here...
that.getView().setModel(that.rdModel, "rdModel");
```

View Binding -->

```html
<Tree id="Tree" items="{path: 'rdModel>/'}">
    <StandardTreeItem id="_IDGenStandardTreeItem1" title=" 
     {rdModel>text}" detailPress="" />
</Tree>
```